# How to check whether an AS3 "Object" variable is completely empty?

Tags: actionscript-3, object, reference-type

In Actionscript 3.0, how do I check if `var myObject:Object` is functionally identical to `{}`?

I take it I can't do ...

```
if (myObject == {}) {
  // etc
}
```

... because Objects are reference types, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check that it exists at least one field :

```
function isEmptyObject(myObject:Object):Boolean {
 var isEmpty:Boolean=true;

 for (var s:String in myObject) {
   isEmpty = false;
   break;
 }

 return isEmpty;
}
```

Comment: There shouldn't be any reason to use a temporary variable, as one could simply use `return false;` inside the `for` statement.

Answer (score 1):

This works with dynamic object and classes, to check if an object contains fields this should be a more general solution

```
import flash.utils.describeType;

var test:String = "test";

var data:XML = describeType(test);
trace(data..accessor.length() > 0 || data..variable.length() > 0)
```

Comment: Although I was asking about dynamic objects, this is an excellent answer! (and welcome to SO!)